# Running a live Rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to web development, rails, etc. I have what is probably a very dumb questions but I searched and was not able to find the specific answer, though there's a good chance I asked the wrong question.

I'm following this tutorial which wants you to create a test rails app locally and view it via localhost in a browser. However I am learning directly on the server itself. This is because currently I only have an iPad to work with, but I've been able to do everything directly on the server itself using Panic's Prompt. To continue with these lessons I need to be able to see what I've done via a browser which since I can't use localhost, I want to see directly on my server. Here is the tutorial I'm following:

http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/create_a_rails_app

Here is my website:

redvardo.com

Any help or pointers toward the correct information would be helpful. Please tell me if I did not include enough information as well. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Phil .  I'm not sure to understand your question, you are running a rails app on a remote server but in development enviroment right ? 
You need to bind to different address than localhost. try rails s -b redvardo.com, and if you dont have a firewall you could access your app from anywhere. on the default 3000 port .

Comment: I will you suggest to try some cloud ide, have a look at https://codeanywhere.com

Comment: I know, I feel stupid asking this stuff. :(

I created the app in a folder of the main so it's at redvardo.com/test_app

Would I then try **rails s -b redvardo.com/test_app**

Comment: You write your code using an iPad?

Answer (score 0):

If your server provides a public IP address, use that ip to access the project. First of all make sure the brick server is running via rails s then you can go ahead and access the page directly via the ip: 12.13.31.115:3000 for example.  This would be the fastest way, otherwise you need to setup dns to point to your server via your domain name registrar.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but for me, what I did was simply install a VNC server on the server itself, now I can view localhost on the server for everything the tutorials are asking.